# Streets change their width while zooming in Google Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-api-javascript-client

I try to put some rectangles on a styled map which can be zoomed in and out. I noticed that every time I change the zoom level from e.g. 17.5 to 17.6, the streets are changing their width and because of that the rectangle changes its position compared to the street.

Code:

- map

  ```
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

  var myOptions = {
      zoom: zoom,
      center: latlng,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      scrollwheel: false,
      disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
      styles: [
          {
              featureType: 'all',
              stylers: [{visibility: "off"}]
          },
          {
              featureType: 'landscape',
              stylers: [{color: "#000000"}, {visibility: "on"}]
          },
          {
              featureType: 'road',
              elementType: 'geometry',
              stylers: [{color: '#ffffff'}, {visibility: "on"}, {weight: 2}]
          }
      ]
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
  ```
- rectangle

  ```
  var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeWeight: 2,
      strokeOpacity: 1,
      map: map,
      bounds: {
          north: lat1,
          south: lat2,
          west: lng1,
          east: lng2
      }
  });
  ```

I want the rectangle to be in the same place of the street at the all zoom levels. Can this be done?

PS. Here's what it looks like:
[zoom=19.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHEJg.png) vs
[zoom=19.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QgU8.png)

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that step-like changing width only occurs when crossing 0.5 - if I change the zoom from `19.2` to `19.3` there is no difference in positions.
See the example:
[zoom=21.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Gf3A.png) vs [zoom=21.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulZrU.png)
I also noticed that rectangle's stroke seems to change its weight less often that the street's one. Can somebody explain the reason of such behavior?

Comment: Well stuff does look bigger when you are closer to it! Im not sure how to fix it, maybe you need to listen to the zoom event on the map and redraw the rectangle?

Comment: You'll have to zoom your rectangle aswell

Comment: @NielsNet, the rectangle has specific lat-lng bounds and is responsible to the zoom change. Do you suggest "refreshing" the rectangle or changing its `strokeWeight` parameter?

Comment: @Fartosh Some kind of refreshing is probably necessary. However due tu rouding there will probably always be a difference.